# Issue to getting flickr contact list

Tags: iphone, ios, flickr

I want to get flickr friends list on my iPhone app. I read documentation and I found the URL for it. But in this URL I do not understand how to pass api_sig tht name parameter. The URL is given below. Can any body help me?

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.contacts.getList&api_key=b201806ce09c404a786288dbd1840b2b&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157629827571110-752bbff651a7654c&api_sig=a8c18f235e27220db724ac97d3216b1a

Comment: refer http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-ultimate-guide-to-decoding-the-flickr-api/

Answer (score 0):

Flickr has updated its authentication protocols recently, so perhaps the information linked by @Nikunj R. Jadav (dated 28 July 2009) is in need of updating.  [Flickr's instructions](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html) on how to sign an API call read:

> Currently, Flickr only supports HMAC-SHA1 signature encryption.
>
> First, you must create a base string from your request. The base string is constructed by concatenating the HTTP verb, the request URL, and all request parameters sorted by name, using lexicograhpical byte value ordering, separated by an '&'.
>
> Use the base string as the text and the key is the concatenated values of the Consumer Secret and Token Secret, separated by an '&'.

You then hash the base string and pass it as the &api_sign query string parameter.

Beyond just signing the API call, you will need to authenticate.  The documentation for the [flickr.contacts.getList](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.contacts.getList.html) API says that it requires authentication with OAuth.  OAuth authentication ([also documented](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html)) is a little tricky; it helps to have a library to manage some of the work for you.  You can find a directory of [libraries for OAuth support in Objective-C](http://oauth.net/code/) at the OAuth site.